# How can I keep one variable seperate from another?

Tags: python

I am writing a function that navigates a map from one corner to the other, this map is in the form of a list of lists, 0's being spaces and 1's being walls. like this:

```
[
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
]
```

My code marks the spaces it's been in with a 2 so that it doesn't go back on itself. the code goes through the map a few times to try to find shorter routes, this means however that every time it goes through, it has to reset the map. It seems however that the variable that the map gets passed to changes every time every other variable with the map changes, so I can't keep an original copy. This only seems to happen when it's passed to the function rather than set within the function. I've tried a few different approaches, like setting multiple other variables, passing each list by appending the variable in a for loop, clearing one of the variables, but I can't seem to find the problem, I've never had this kind of problem before and I'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll likely want to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are passing your map (which is a list of lists) to a function, and find it surprising that the function changes the original map you pass to it. However, this is expected behavior under many list operations.

The underlying issue is that [Python lists are mutable.](https://medium.com/@meghamohan/mutable-and-immutable-side-of-python-c2145cf72747) This means that operations like `a[i] = b` will modify the list in-place.

Consider the following example:

```py
a_list = [1, 2, 3]

def foo(l):
    l[0] += 1
    return l

b_list = foo(a_list)
```

Here, we find that

```py
>>> b_list
[2, 2, 3]

>>> a_list
[2, 2, 3]

>>> a_list is b_list
True
```

If you want to prevent this, you will have to create a copy of the list before modifying it:

```py
import copy

def foo_2(l):
    # this creates a copy of the list and all sublists
    l = copy.deepcopy(l)
    l[0] += 1
    return l

b_list = foo_2(a_list)
```

Now, we find the following:

```py
>>> b_list
[2, 2, 3]

>>> a_list
[1, 2, 3]

>>> a_list is b_list
False
```

You could do the same with your map before passing it on, or be more careful to avoid in-place operations on your data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code?

Instead of directly passing your original map to the function that is navigating through the map. Simply copy the map and store it in another variable. Pass this new variable to the function that is navigating through the map.